# Swift: How to tell if a scheduled local notification is working?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have created a local notification to fire every 2 hours on weekdays but not sure how you tell if the notification is firing or not.

```
@IBAction func scheduleLocal(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() else { return
    }
    if settings.types == .None {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Cant Schedule", message: "No Permission", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    //Monday 9am

    var dateComp: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComp.year = 2016;
    dateComp.month = 03;
    dateComp.day = 07;
    dateComp.hour = 9;
    dateComp.minute = 0;
    dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    var calender:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    var date:NSDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!


    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.alertBody = "Begin!"
    notification.alertAction = "Start"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["customField1": "w00t"]
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: you can try and change the date of your iphone/simulator

Comment: set `notification.fireDate` to `nil` to fire it immediately.

Comment: Not getting question properly! If you are asking that how to know that it will work or not then you can try by firing on every minute or can change time of device or simulator

Comment: ah thanks guys, appears to be working after changing the firedate to nil! cheers for your help